# Rails Loop Through Comma Delimited String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have jquery posting

```
params[:comment][:attachments] = 09ff86a136c05c82a43fed917e5cdbe9bc44e11a82329c6e923935671ed4bf6b, 840bc6197294c6a8c4393803fa16463d28a2520b33d4a0520e905f8b83399d11
```

I then want to be able to loop through the comma delimited list in Rails, here's what I have so far:

```
params[:comment][:attachments].each do |uuid|
 uuid
end
```

Problem is uuid is listing the entire string.. Ideas to loop through the comma delimited list in Rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
params[:comment][:attachments].split(/, ?/).each ...
```

Answer (score 2):

to make an array

```
params[:comment][:attachments].split(",").each do |uuid|
  #stuff
end
```